# app store review error: 'the binary must be an executable'

Tags: ios

I am trying to upload an app for Apple to review, but am not sure what I am doing wrong to receive this error message: `the binary must be an executable`.

At last, I generate the `ProjectName.app`, then `chmod 755 .../ProjectName.app/ProjectName` all of the files in the `ProjectName.app` dictionary.

I don't know why it's not executable. I want to know how to configure it.

Comment: normally it is because of your app crashes when launching. check ur app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason is a misconfiguration in Xcode. Check **Build Settings**, under **Linking**, that **Mach-O Type** is set to **Executable**.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this,but it does not work;   I gernarate the ProjectName.app, then chmod 755 .../ProjectName.app/ProjectName of all files in the ProjectName.app dictionary;

But I don't know why it's not executable, I want to know how to config it;